# Zoom sensitivity in Bing Maps

Tags: ajax, maps, bing-maps, bing-api

I've been using Bing Maps AJAX control and was wondering if there was any way to adjust the sensitivity of the zoom controls. They seem overly sensitive, appearing to jump levels. Is there any way to restrict the number of levels zoomed per click?

Answer (score 0):

1. Override the default mouse/touch behavior by subscribing to the relevant events on the map
2. Implement zooming in the event handlers to your liking.
3. Set the "handled" property on the event to true, so the default map control behavior for the event is cancelled.